# How to check if a Hamiltonian is PT symmetric or not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

Consider the Hamiltonian

$$H=p^2+ix^3+ix.$$

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9712001) by Carl M bender claims this is a $PT$ symmetric Hamiltonian. In this he describes $PT$ symmetry as

> parity $P$, whose effect is to make spatial reflections, 
>   $$p\to-p\text{ and }x\to -x$$
>   time reversal $T$, which replaces
>   $$p\to -p,\ x\to-x\text{, and }i\to-i.$$

If I carry out these operations, the Hamiltonian $H$ is only invariant under time reversal $T$ and not invariant under $P$ (spatial reflections).

Is there any other way to check if a Hamiltonian is $PT$ symmetric? Please illustrate with the above example.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): OP's time reversal transformation contains an error.

Comment: What is the error? I have written it exactly as mentioned in the paper.

Comment: The version of the paper i have seemed to have the mistake . but the current versions doesn't ,seems the editors took some time to edit it out..

Comment: Bender's paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0501052) offers an excellent numerical example for determining if a Hamiltonian is parity time symmetric. Just scroll to section "VI. ILLUSTRATIVE EXAMPLE: A 2×2 MATRIX HAMILTONIAN".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in your definition of time reversal as $x$ is fixed under that transformation, the remaining transformations being correct. With this correct version of T, the Hamiltonian you study is PT symmetric.