# Proving that hamiltonian is $PT$-symmetric

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

I have recently started studying about $PT$-symmetric Hamiltonians.

Is Hamiltonian $H=p^2+ix$ $PT$-symmetric?

If yes, would its energy eigenvalues be real?
Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: It is not hermitian under the usual inner product so why should it’s eigenvalues be real?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That's the magic of PT-symmetric nonhermitean Hamiltonians: they *may* have real eigenvalues. But this one arguably has only one, the ground state, but...

Comment: @CosmasZachos right but it seems the OP's question is much broader than just a question on the ground state.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for your response! Could you explain to me how did you conclude that this Hamiltonian has only one real eigenvalue? That would be great help to me!

Comment: I adduced a reference in my answer, in which, of course, you take the infinite λ limit, and you may always go to the classic  Bender &  Boettcher, *PhysRevLett* **80** (1998) 5243, that you should  almost know by heart. This is a messy problem and needs care, in case you are asking for a facile argument.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for your help!

Comment: similar to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255654/how-to-check-if-a-hamiltonian-is-pt-symmetric-or-not

Answer (score 1):

You recall that
$$
PpP=-p; ~~~PxP=-x; \\ ~~~TxT= x; ~~~ TpT=-p; ~~~TiT=-i,\\
P^2=T^2=1\!\!1; ~~~[P,T]=0.
$$
These two operators preserve the canonical commutation relations, separately.

You may then see both the kinetic and potential terms of your hamiltonian are PT symmetric,
$$PT~ix~PT= ix. $$

Yes, real for the (divergent) ground state energy (only). Write down your Airy solutions. (Hint: [Lombard & Mezhoud](http://hal.in2p3.fr/in2p3-01997748/document) bash it to a pulp.)